# How to fetch multiple key-value pairs array in Java Script/TestCafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, keyvaluepair

```
const passnegerGroup = [
  { FIRSTNAME: 'RAHUL', LASTNAME: 'KUMAR' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'RINA', LASTNAME: 'KUMAR' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'SOHAN', LASTNAME: 'SINGH' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'PAUL', LASTNAME: 'ANDERSON' },
];

// I want to read each passenger's last name and first name and do some operations.

// Tried this code but this is

for (const key of Object.values(passnegerGroup)) {
  console.log(key.FIRSTNAME, key.LASTNAME);
}
```

output :

RAHUL KUMAR
RINA KUMAR
SOHAN SINGH
PAUL ANDERSON

This is working for but getting ESLINT error.
`ESLint: iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime`, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations. (no-restricted-syntax)

Kindly help me achieve the above using some modern JavaScript/TestCafe codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const passnegerGroup = [
  { FIRSTNAME: 'RAHUL', LASTNAME: 'KUMAR' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'RINA', LASTNAME: 'KUMAR' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'SOHAN', LASTNAME: 'SINGH' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'PAUL', LASTNAME: 'ANDERSON' },
];

//No garantee that firstname comes before lastname
const result1 = passnegerGroup.map( u => Object.values(u) ).flat().join(' ');
console.log(result1);

const result2 = passnegerGroup.map( u => [u.FIRSTNAME, u.LASTNAME]).flat().join(' ');
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. It's working for me. Though I don't need to join so I have used till passnegerGroup.map(u => Object.values(u)) and it worked. I will accept it.

Comment: It works but its overkill of tranformations. Better to be more explicit of output - by using reduce method rather than map, because it return an array which then needs further formatting.

Comment: Yes you're right, clearly not optimized. @shashankshekhar, if you're using a 20Mhz cpu, this 3chained method on a 4 sized array is totally overkill haha

Comment: Its more about steps of understanding. 
Map method returns an array, but you want a string. pure programming principle.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const passnegerGroup = [
  { FIRSTNAME: 'RAHUL', LASTNAME: 'KUMAR' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'RINA', LASTNAME: 'KUMAR' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'SOHAN', LASTNAME: 'SINGH' },
  { FIRSTNAME: 'PAUL', LASTNAME: 'ANDERSON' },
];

const result = passnegerGroup.reduce((accum, cur) => `${accum} ${cur.FIRSTNAME} ${cur.LASTNAME} `, '');

console.log('result =', result);
```